# Java springboot process stuck

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a java springboot process that gets hung after multiple requests to an endpoint.

There are no blocking threads but there are threads stuck waiting. Here is an example:

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-50" #2144 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=12.18ms elapsed=1266.15s allocated=217K defined_classes=0 tid=0x00007f919c049000 nid=0xcd8 waiting on condition  [0x00007f910bcf8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.8/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000701e9ef98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.8/LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.8/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:1323)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:306)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:223)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:141)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:265)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
        at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.findById(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:427)
        at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.findById(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:133)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getRequestedSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:356)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:290)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:193)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager.retrieveFlashMaps(SessionFlashMapManager.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractFlashMapManager.retrieveAndUpdate(AbstractFlashMapManager.java:95)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:948)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        - locked <0x000000072758cb60> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.8/Thread.java:834)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000007276fd9e8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

How do I go about debugging this? Dump came from jstack and the process runs in a kubernetes container.

I am the system engineer not developer so I don't have much experience with dubugging java

Answer (score 1):

This thread appears to be a worker thread handling an HTTP request, and it's trying to obtain a database connection from a connection pool. However, since the pool might be empty or there could be some contention, the thread is currently waiting for a connection to become available.

To address this issue, ensure that the connection pool configuration is appropriate for your application's requirements and expected load. Increasing the number of connections in a database connection pool by configuring the data source properties appropriately may resolve the issue.